# avoid having 'index' in url when using a variable in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

When you want to have a link like

`http://www.domain.com/users/54/John`

In Cakephp you have to rewrite it to:

`http://www.domain.com/users/index/54/John`

If you don't do this cakephp complains that within the `users` controller there is no action called `54`. Is there no other way around this? Like to tell cakephp that when the second variable in the url is a number (so in this case 54), to refer it to the index function:

`public function index($userId = null)`.

Another example is the url of this question. If it was cakephp, the url would look like:

`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/index/18547494/avoid-having..`

Is it in cakephp possible to do something like this?

`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18547494/avoid-having..`

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: You should be using query strings and probably some custom routing. This avoids this issue completely - in a clean and future proof way.

Answer (score 1):

```
Router::connect('/users/:id/:name', array(
    'controller' => 'users',
    'action' => 'index'
), array('pass' => array('id', 'name')));
```

Your controller action code should be like this:

```
public function index($id = null, $name = null) {
    // your code
}
```

In your view you can define link as follows to access the url

```
echo $this->Html->link('view', array(
    'controller'  => 'users',
    'action' => 'index'
    'id' => $yourid,
    'name' => $yourname
))
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use the id key in the routing array when creating links. Something like this:

```
array(
    'controller'=>'users', 'action'=>'index', 'id' => 54
}
```

Comment: then it will still put `index` in the url

Answer (score 0):

You should have have this:

```
Router::connect(
   '/:controller/:id',
   array('action' => 'view'),
   array('id' => '[0-9]+')
);
```

Read: [Routing in CakePHP](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html)